# Empty Arraylist

Tags: java, android

So, in my android application I'm trying to convert a Json link to a list view, but when I send the ArrayList, I get an empty one.

My code:

**Class fetchData**

```
public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    String data="";
    String dataParsed="";
    String singleParsed="";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line = "";


            while ( line != null){
                line = bf.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);

            for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                Person p = new Person(jo.getString("id"),jo.getString("name"),jo.getString("username"),jo.getString("email"));
                this.persons.add(p);
                singleParsed =p.toString();
                dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        MainActivity.informations= this.dataParsed;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button moreInfos;

    public static ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public static String informations;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        moreInfos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goInfos);

        fetchData process = new fetchData();
        process.execute();

        moreInfos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Informations.class);
                String message = informations;
                intent.putExtra("msg", message);
                startActivity(intent);


                // normally we need to pass the arraylist that contains the list of our persons
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now in my MainActivity if I check the size of my ArrayList persons I get 0, can anyone help me or direct me so I can solve this problem?

Comment: Why you define two arraylist with same name ?

Comment: `static` field `MainActivity.persons` is never touched and therefore stays empty. What does `process.getPersons().size()` tell you?

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming convents. Class names go UpperCase. Always. You should also prefer `List<Whatever> foo = new ArrayList<>()` instead of using ArrayList as type of your fields!

Comment: @Selaron it tells me that it has 0 elements

Comment: Are you sure `process.doInBackground();` actually finisched background work and found a person when checking the list size? Maybe you are checking too fast.

Comment: @Selaron How can i please check if process.doInBackground(); has finished background work ?

Comment: What'sm the return type of `process.execute();` ? Is it a Future? If so, its' `get()` method would wait until completion of `doInBackground()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list in your activity is empty because you never actually put anything in it. Keep in mind that the list in your async task is *different* from the one in your activity, so you have to actually copy it.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    MainActivity.informations = this.dataParsed;
    // defensively copy
    MainActivity.persons = new ArrayList<>(this.persons);
}
```

There are a few other things you could improve in your code (like using static fields in your activity when you should be using callbacks) but this should fix the immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
public static ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

And:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

So there are **two** completely different lists. And it seems your adding elements only to that second list in `fetchData()`. A first fix would be to simply remove that second declaration and go:

```
MainActivity.persons.add(p);
```

instead. But of course: using static variables like that, and blindly pushing elements into it (from other classes) is most likely a bad idea.